# Rails each_slice displaying array at bottom of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using `each_slice` successfully - it works as expected. However, it is also displaying the array contents at the bottom of the page, as if I've added a `puts` there.

I have a very simple controller method:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Here's the view:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-12{ style: "margin-top: 25px;" }
      %h1#intro-h Posts
  .row
    .col-md-12

  - @posts.each_slice(2) do |group|
    .row{style: 'margin-bottom: 30px;'}
      = group.each do |post|
        .col-md-2
          = image_tag post.user.profile_image.url, style: "height: 100px; border-radius: 50%;"
        .col-md-4
          %h3{style: 'margin-top: -5px;'}
            = link_to post.title, post
          Created by
          = post.first_name
          = post.last_name
          %br
          %p
            .row
              .col-md-4
                = link_to "Read more", post, class: "btn btn-default", style: "margin-top: 8px; width: 100px;", method: :get
              .col-md-4

= render 'paginator'
```

And this gets displayed at the bottom of the page:

`[#<Post id: 3, title: "Test Post", user_id: 3, description: "Test Post", slug: "test-post", featured_image: nil>]`

Any idea how to get rid of that array display at the bottom of the page?

Comment: It's because of this `= group.each do |post|`, remove the `=`. Try if that works.

Comment: That was it - thanks so much - that was a typo. Changed ```=``` to ```-``` and it removed the array. Great eye!

Comment: Nice, you can delete the question as it fits in the off-topic  _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_.

Comment: Agreed to @SebastianPalma that the question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part is `= group.each do |post|` since `each` returns the array itself as well in addition to running the loop. And since you have an `=` sign before it so the `=` in the `view` would also render the returned output of the `group.each` statement. You may want to use `-` as `- group.each do |post|` as it will render the output of `group.each`.